# symfony2.6 route with query params (KnpPaginatorBundle and WhiteOctoberPagerfantaBundle)

Tags: php, symfony, pagination, symfony-2.6

Trying to use KnpPaginatorBundle and WhiteOctoberPagerfantaBundle

If i have url

`/categories/tech/plates`

next page url show me

`/catalog/categories/tech/plates?/catalog/categories/tech/plates=&page=2`

I can not understand why this is happening :(
Can anyone help?
What am I doing wrong?

```php
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = [
            // default symfony project
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),

            // additional
//          new Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle(),
            new SimpleThings\EntityAudit\SimpleThingsEntityAuditBundle(),
            new Sonata\IntlBundle\SonataIntlBundle(),
            new FOS\JsRoutingBundle\FOSJsRoutingBundle(),
            new A2lix\TranslationFormBundle\A2lixTranslationFormBundle(),
            new WhiteOctober\PagerfantaBundle\WhiteOctoberPagerfantaBundle(),
            new Bazinga\Bundle\JsTranslationBundle\BazingaJsTranslationBundle(),

            // admin panel
            new Sonata\CoreBundle\SonataCoreBundle(),
            new Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle(),
            new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle(),
            new Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle(),
            new Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle(),
            new Application\Sonata\AdminBundle\ApplicationSonataAdminBundle(),
            new Sonata\MediaBundle\SonataMediaBundle(),
            new CoopTilleuls\Bundle\CKEditorSonataMediaBundle\CoopTilleulsCKEditorSonataMediaBundle(),
            new Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\ApplicationSonataMediaBundle(),

//            // users
            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
            new Sonata\UserBundle\SonataUserBundle('FOSUserBundle'),
            new Sonata\EasyExtendsBundle\SonataEasyExtendsBundle(),
            new Application\Sonata\UserBundle\ApplicationSonataUserBundle(),
            new FOS\OAuthServerBundle\FOSOAuthServerBundle(),
            new Application\FOS\OAuthServerBundle\ApplicationFOSOAuthServerBundle(),
//            new HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\HWIOAuthBundle(),
//            new Xxx\Bundle\OAuthUserBundle\XxxOAuthUserBundle(),

            // rest api default
            new FOS\RestBundle\FOSRestBundle(),
            new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle(),
            new Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\NelmioApiDocBundle(),
            new Application\FOS\RestBundle\ApplicationFOSRestBundle(),

            // form
            new Ivory\OrderedFormBundle\IvoryOrderedFormBundle(), //order fields with 'position' attribute

            //form types
            new Genemu\Bundle\FormBundle\GenemuFormBundle(),
            new Stnw\DatePickerBundle\StnwDatePickerBundle(),
            new Ivory\CKEditorBundle\IvoryCKEditorBundle(),
            new Misd\PhoneNumberBundle\MisdPhoneNumberBundle(),

            // charts
//            new Ob\HighchartsBundle\ObHighchartsBundle(),

            // grid
            new APY\DataGridBundle\APYDataGridBundle(),

//            new Lunetics\LocaleBundle\LuneticsLocaleBundle(),
            new JMS\I18nRoutingBundle\JMSI18nRoutingBundle(),
            new JMS\TranslationBundle\JMSTranslationBundle(),

            // project
            new Xxx\Bundle\AppBundle\XxxAppBundle(),
            new Xxx\Bundle\CompanyBundle\XxxCompanyBundle(),
            new Xxx\Bundle\TransactionBundle\XxxTransactionBundle(),
            new Xxx\Bundle\StoreBundle\XxxStoreBundle(),
            new Xxx\Bundle\DeviceBundle\XxxDeviceBundle(),
            new Xxx\Bundle\CatalogBundle\XxxCatalogBundle(),
            new Xxx\Bundle\ChipBundle\XxxChipBundle(),
            new Xxx\Bundle\CityBundle\XxxCityBundle(),
            new Xxx\Bundle\LastActivityBundle\XxxLastActivityBundle(),

            // frontend
            new WhiteOctober\BreadcrumbsBundle\WhiteOctoberBreadcrumbsBundle(),
            new Xxx\ContactBundle\XxxContactBundle(),
            new Application\Xxx\ContactBundle\ApplicationXxxContactBundle(),
            new Xxx\Bundle\FaqBundle\XxxFaqBundle(),
            new Xxx\Bundle\NewsBundle\XxxNewsBundle(),
            new Xxx\Bundle\MenuBundle\XxxMenuBundle(),
            new Xxx\Bundle\PageBundle\XxxPageBundle(),
            new Xxx\Bundle\SmsGatewayBundle\XxxSmsGatewayBundle(),
        ];

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'])) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();

            // translator, needed for grid
            $bundles[] = new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle();
//            $bundles[] = new JMS\TranslationBundle\JMSTranslationBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

```yaml
# app/config/config.yml
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: ../../vendor/knplabs/doctrine-behaviors/config/orm-services.yml }

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    exception_controller: 'FOS\RestBundle\Controller\ExceptionController::showAction'
    form:
        resources:
            - 'StnwDatePickerBundle:Form:fields.html.twig'
            - 'XxxAppBundle:Form:fields.html.twig'
    globals:
        locales: "%locales%"

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        types:
            json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType
            phone_number: Misd\PhoneNumberBundle\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\PhoneNumberType
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
        # e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        # path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
#    spool:     { type: memory }

sensio_framework_extra:
    view:
        annotations: false

fos_rest:
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
        formats:
            xml:  true
            json: true
        templating_formats:
            html: true
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: ^/, priorities: [ html, json, xml ], fallback_format: ~, prefer_extension: true }
    exception:
        codes:
            'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException': 404
            'Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException': HTTP_CONFLICT
        messages:
            'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException': true
    allowed_methods_listener: true
    access_denied_listener:
        json: true
#    serializer:
#        serialize_null: true
    body_listener: true
    disable_csrf_role: ROLE_API

nelmio_api_doc:
    name: Xxx REST API
    sandbox:
        authentication:
            delivery: http
#            name:     apiKey
            type:     bearer         # `basic`, `bearer` are supported

sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        # Enable the SonataAdminBundle block
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]
        sonata.admin.block.search_result:
            contexts:   [admin]

        # Your other blocks
        sonata.user.block.menu:    # used to display the menu in profile pages
        sonata.user.block.account: # used to display menu option (login option)

        sonata.block.service.text:
        sonata.block.service.action:
        sonata.block.service.rss:

sonata_admin:
    title:      Xxx
#    title_logo: bundles/acmedemo/img/fancy_acme_logo.png
    templates:
        # default global templates
        layout:  ApplicationSonataAdminBundle::layout.html.twig
        ajax:    SonataAdminBundle::ajax_layout.html.twig

        # default actions templates, should extend a global templates
        list:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list.html.twig
        show:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show.html.twig
        edit:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:edit.html.twig
        search:  SonataAdminBundle:Core:search.html.twig
        search_result_block: SonataAdminBundle:Block:block_search_result.html.twig

    dashboard:
        blocks:
            # display a dashboard block
            - { position: left, type: sonata.admin.block.admin_list }

        groups:
            default:

            fos_user:
                label: menu.group_users
                items: [sonata.user.admin.user, sonata.user.admin.group]

            xxx_company:
                label: menu.group_company
                items: [xxx.admin.company, xxx.admin.company_category, xxx.admin.store, xxx.admin.device]

            xxx_catalog:
                label: menu.group_catalog
                items: [xxx.admin.catalog.product, xxx.admin.catalog.product_category, xxx.admin.chip.rule]

            xxx_transaction:
                  label: menu.group_transaction
                  items: [xxx.admin.transaction]

            xxx_media:
                  label: menu.group_media
                  items: [sonata.media.admin.media]

            xxx_news:
                  label: menu.group_news
                  items: [xxx.news.admin.news]

            xxx_faq:
                  label: menu.group_faq
                  items: [xxx.faq.admin.faq]

            xxx_page:
                  label: menu.group_page
                  items: [xxx_page.admin.page]

            xxx_menu:
                  label: menu.group_menu
                  items: [xxx_menu.admin.menu, xxx_menu.admin.menu_type]

            xxx_city:
                  label: menu.group_city
                  items: [xxx_city.admin.city]

            xxx_sms_gateway:
                  label: menu.group_sms_gateway
                  items: [xxx_sms_gateway.admin.message]

    security:
        handler: sonata.admin.security.handler.role
            # acl security information
        information:
            ADMIN:    [MASTER]
        # permissions not related to an object instance and also to be available when objects do not exist
        # the DELETE admin permission means the user is allowed to batch delete objects
        admin_permissions: [CREATE, LIST, DELETE, UNDELETE, EXPORT, OPERATOR, MASTER]
        # permission related to the objects
        object_permissions: [VIEW, EDIT, DELETE, UNDELETE, OPERATOR, MASTER, OWNER]
    options:
        html5_validate: true # does not use html5 validation
        confirm_exit:   false # disable confirmation when quitting with unsaved changes
        use_select2:    true # disable select2
        pager_links:    5     # pager max links to display

    # set to true to persist filter settings per admin module in the user's session
    persist_filters: false

#read http://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/2-2/doc/reference/installation.html
sonata_media:
    # if you don't use default namespace configuration
    #class:
    #    media: MyVendor\MediaBundle\Entity\Media
    #    gallery: MyVendor\MediaBundle\Entity\Gallery
    #    gallery_has_media: MyVendor\MediaBundle\Entity\GalleryHasMedia
    default_context: default
    db_driver: doctrine_orm # or doctrine_mongodb, doctrine_phpcr

    contexts:
        default:  # the default context is mandatory
            providers:
#                - sonata.media.provider.dailymotion
                - sonata.media.provider.youtube
                - sonata.media.provider.image
#                - sonata.media.provider.file

            formats: ~
                small: { width: 100 , quality: 70}
                big:   { width: 500 , quality: 70}

    cdn:
        server:
            path: /uploads/media # http://media.sonata-project.org/

    filesystem:
        local:
            directory:  %kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/media
            create:     false

# Notice: EntityAudit currently only works with a DBAL Connection and EntityManager named "default".
simple_things_entity_audit:
    # таблицы мультиперевода автоматически НЕ цепляются, поэтому нужно указывать в ручную в этом списке
    audited_entities:
        - Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
        - Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group

    # If you need to exclude some entity properties from triggering a revision use:
#    global_ignore_columns:
#        - created_at
#        - updated_at

sonata_intl:
    timezone:
        default: Europe/Moscow
        detectors:
            - sonata.intl.timezone_detector.user
            - sonata.intl.timezone_detector.locale
        locales:
            ru:    Europe/Chisinau

fos_user:
    db_driver:      orm # can be orm or odm
    firewall_name:  admin
    user_class:     Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address:        noreply@xxx.com
        sender_name:    Xxx Noreply
    registration:
        form:
            type:               application_sonata_user_registration
            handler:            fos_user.registration.form.handler.default
            name:               fos_user_registration_form
            validation_groups:  [XxxRegistration]
        confirmation:
            enabled:    true
            template:   ApplicationSonataUserBundle:Registration:email.txt.twig
    profile:
       form:
            type:               application_fos_user_profile
            handler:            fos_user.profile.form.handler.default
            name:               fos_user_profile_form
            validation_groups:  [Authentication]
    change_password:
        form:
            type:               application_fos_user_change_password
            handler:            fos_user.change_password.form.handler.default
            name:               fos_user_change_password_form
            validation_groups:  [ChangePassword, Default]
    group:
        group_class:   Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group
        group_manager: sonata.user.orm.group_manager                    # If you're using doctrine orm

    service:
        user_manager: sonata.user.orm.user_manager                      # If you're using doctrine orm
        mailer: fos_user.mailer.twig_swift

sonata_user:
    security_acl:     false
    class:
        user:         Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
        group:        Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group

    profile:  # Profile Form (firstname, lastname, etc ...)
        form:
            type:               application_sonata_user_profile
            handler:            sonata_user.form.handler.profile
            name:               sonata_user_profile_form
            validation_groups:  [Profile]
    impersonating:
        route:              sonata_admin_dashboard

parameters:
    sonata.user.admin.user.class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\UserAdmin
    knp.doctrine_behaviors.blameable_listener.user_entity: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\UserAdmin
#    sonata.user.admin.user.translation_xxxin: ApplicationUserBundle

fos_oauth_server:
    db_driver: orm       # Driver availables: orm, mongodb, or propel
    client_class:        Application\FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Entity\Client
    access_token_class:  Application\FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Entity\AccessToken
    refresh_token_class: Application\FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Entity\RefreshToken
    auth_code_class:     Application\FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Entity\AuthCode
    service:
        user_provider: fos_user.user_manager
        options:
            access_token_lifetime: 3600 #seconds
            token_type: Bearer
#            supported_scopes: oauth_scope_scanner test1

fos_js_routing:
    cache_control:
        # All are optional, defaults shown
        public: false   # can be true (public) or false (private)
        maxage: null    # integer value, e.g. 300
        smaxage: null   # integer value, e.g. 300
        expires: null   # anything that can be fed to "new \DateTime($expires)", e.g. "5 minutes"
        vary: []        # string or array, e.g. "Cookie" or [ Cookie, Accept ]

jms_serializer:
    metadata:
        auto_detection: true
        directories:
            SonataUserBundle:
                namespace_prefix: "Sonata\\UserBundle"
                path: "@ApplicationSonataUserBundle/Resources/config/serializer/SonataUserBundle"
            FOSUserBundle:
                namespace_prefix: "FOS\\UserBundle"
                path: "@ApplicationSonataUserBundle/Resources/config/serializer/FOSUserBundle/"

white_october_pagerfanta:
    exceptions_strategy:
        out_of_range_page:        to_http_not_found
        not_valid_current_page:   to_http_not_found

apy_data_grid:
    limits: [20, 50, 100]
    pagerfanta:
        enable: true    #default false
        view_class: Pagerfanta\View\TwitterBootstrap3View #default    Pagerfanta\View\DefaultView
        options:            #all options of pager fanta view constructor
           prev_message : «
           next_message : »

genemu_form:
    date: ~
    captcha: ~
#    tinymce: ~

a2lix_translation_form:
    locales: %locales%       # [1]
    required_locales: %locales%      # [2]
    manager_registry: doctrine      # [3]
    templating: "A2lixTranslationFormBundle::default.html.twig"      # [4]

white_october_breadcrumbs:
    viewTemplate:       "XxxAppBundle:Breadcrumbs:breadcrumbs.html.twig"
    separator:          ""

ivory_ck_editor:
    default_config: default
    configs:
        default:
            filebrowserBrowseRoute: admin_sonata_media_media_browser
            filebrowserImageBrowseRoute: admin_sonata_media_media_browser
            # Display images by default when clicking the image dialog browse button
            filebrowserImageBrowseRouteParameters:
                provider: sonata.media.provider.image
            filebrowserUploadRoute: admin_sonata_media_media_upload
            filebrowserUploadRouteParameters:
                provider: sonata.media.provider.file
            # Upload file as image when sending a file from the image dialog
            filebrowserImageUploadRoute: admin_sonata_media_media_upload
            filebrowserImageUploadRouteParameters:
                provider: sonata.media.provider.image
                context: my-context # Optional, to upload in a custom context

xxx_transaction:
    sms_confirmation: %transaction_sms_confirmation%

xxx_contact:
    store_data:            false
    contact_class:         Xxx\ContactBundle\Model\BaseContact

    form:
        type:              application_xxx_contact
#        handler:           xxx_contact.form.handler.default
#        name:              contact_form
#        validation_groups: [Default]
#        subject_provider:  xxx_contact.subject_provider.noop
        captcha_type:      genemu_captcha
#
    email:
#        mailer:            xxx_contact.mailer.twig_swift
        recipient_address: "%admin_email%" # Required
#        template:          XxxContactBundle:Contact:email.txt.twig

jms_i18n_routing:
    default_locale: %locale%
    locales: %locales%
    strategy: prefix_except_default

xxx_sms_gateway:
    monolog_handler: monolog.logger.sms_gateway
    message:
        class: Xxx\Bundle\SmsGatewayBundle\Entity\Message
        manager: xxx_sms_gateway.entity.message_manager
    default_gateway: bulk_sms
    gateways:
        bulk_sms:
            sender: %sms_gateway_bulk_sms_sender%
            username: %sms_gateway_bulk_sms_username%
            password: %sms_gateway_bulk_sms_password%
            mode:
                charset: plaintext # plaintext, utf8, windows-1251
                max_number_of_chars: 160 # 160 for plaintext, 70 for UTF8 and Windows 1251
#                base_url: http://79.170.224.75/BulkSMSAPI/UnifunBulkSMSAPI.asmx/SendSMSNoneDigitsEncoded
                base_url: http://79.170.224.75/BulkSMSAPI/UnifunBulkSMSAPI.asmx/SendSMSSimple
            report:
                enabled: false
                mask: 31 # 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 31
                route: xxx_sms_gateway_sms_report_bulk_sms

bazinga_js_translation:
    locale_fallback: %locale%
    active_locales: %locales%
    default_xxxin: XxxAppBundle

xxx_last_activity:
    audited_entities:
#        - Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User # при регистарции нет имени
        - Xxx\Bundle\CompanyBundle\Entity\Company
        - Xxx\Bundle\FaqBundle\Entity\Faq
        - Xxx\Bundle\NewsBundle\Entity\News
```

Standart pagination with pagerfanta

```
{% if pagination.haveToPaginate %}
    {{ pagerfanta(pagination, 'twitter_bootstrap3_translated') }}
{% endif %}
```

Standart pagination call

```
// return some query
$query = $this->getManager()->getQueryAllByCategory($findCompaniesByCategory); 
$page = $request->query->get('page', 1);

$pagination = new Pagerfanta(new DoctrineORMAdapter($query));
$pagination
    ->setMaxPerPage($this->container->getParameter('items_on_page'))
    ->setCurrentPage($page)
;
```

Comment: We don't know anything about your configuration but looks like your routing are incorrect somehow, if you want an answer we need more information and more data. try to update your question with the routing and how you implement it.

Comment: I guess a minimal working example (MWE) could also improve your chances for an answer and help others to understand the actual problem